# When is 助けてください appropriate?

Tags: words

I want to ask for help with learning Japanese. Is 助けてください appropriate for this situation? Should I use something else? Is a particle needed in the request?

Comment: [助]{たす}けてください would be appropriate in some contexts, [手伝]{てつだ}ってください, in other contexts. So, what's your context?

Comment: @Chocolate I revised my question. Thank you. I am chatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as Chocolate said, there are two main ways to ask for "help"

助{たす}けてください  is used for situations in which you feel some distress.

手伝{てつだ}ってください is used for situations where you would like some assistance.

you have another choice as well, you could ask for the specific type of help you want, in this case, help learning Japanese. So you could say

日本語{にほんご}の勉強{べんきょう}を手伝{てつだ}ってください。

or

日本語 教{おし}えてください。This one, "Please teach me Japanese." sounds a little too forceful, though. Use with caution.